# Delete a range of email messages using the 'mail' command

Tags: solaris, email, mail-command

I have about 1k+ mails in an inbox (old cronjob stdout).  How do I delete them in bulk?

I'm on Solaris 8 and I have only `mail` available, no `pine` or `mutt` or similar "UI"-based client.

Inline help and man page only give `d #` to delete a specific mail. I've tried for example `d 1 - 100` but no luck. And I don't feel like doing `d` 1000 times.

Any ideas how to clean up this inbox? I'd actually like to purge all mails older than x days.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While `mail` may not be able to, and you don't have `pine` or `mutt` you probably *do* have `mailx`. And `mailx` can `d 5-10` or `d *`.

Comment: `mail` on macOS also supports ranges. `d 1-100` works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute a `d 1` through `d 100`, you could generate that sequence of commands and pipe it directly to `mail`:

```
i=1; while [ $i -le 100 ]; do echo d $i; i=$(($i+1)); done | mail
```

Comment: I have no Solaris here to check. If you run `d 1`, does it renumber subsequent emails? If so, you need to either loop backwards or run `d 1` 100 times.

Comment: It does not appear to renumber until all the commands have been run, so `do echo "d $i"` seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

The following will help you to read the mails during 1 second, delete the mail and move on to the next one. If all mails have been deleted loop will stop.

Want some more time? Change sleep to 2 or more. Want it faster? Replace sleep 1 by a dummy command.

```
while (echo dq |mail) do sleep 1 ;done
```