# Can't delete system email

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

While running Postfix on an Ubuntu, I have acquired a number of test email in an account `usr1`, and now I want to delete them before starting other testing. However, every time I try to delete using both `d #` and 'delete #`, nothing happens.

Example:

```
usr1@usr1:~$ mail  
"/var/mail/usr1": 5 messages 5 unread  
>U   1 usr2              Tue Apr 30 15:54  19/478   Testing local mail  
U   2 Mail Delivery Syst Tue Apr 30 15:54  78/2433  Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
U   3 usr2               Tue Apr 30 15:55  19/614   Re: Testing local mail
U   4 usr2               Tue Apr 30 15:55  19/604   Re: Testing local mail
U   5 Mail Delivery Syst Tue Apr 30 15:55  73/2219  Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
? d 1-5
? x

usr1@usr1:~$ mail
"/var/mail/usr1": 5 messages 5 unread
>U   1 usr2              Tue Apr 30 15:54  19/478   Testing local mail
U   2 Mail Delivery Syst Tue Apr 30 15:54  78/2433  Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
U   3 usr2               Tue Apr 30 15:55  19/614   Re: Testing local mail
U   4 usr2               Tue Apr 30 15:55  19/604   Re: Testing local mail
U   5 Mail Delivery Syst Tue Apr 30 15:55  73/2219  Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
? x
```

Can anyone explain why this is? [Another Unix SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/how-to-delete-a-range-of-mails-in-solaris-using-the-mail-command) talks about using the command as I'd expect it to work (granted, in Solaris), but I don't understand why those mails refuse to delete.

Comment: The answer is to exit from mail using `quit` or `q` instead of `exit` or `x`. Full answer once SE lets me answer my own.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After much digging, I realized that the problem was that I always exited from `mail` using either `exit` or `x`. From the [Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/bsd-mailx.1.html):

```
exit (ex or x) Effects an immediate return to the shell without modifying 
               the user's system mailbox, his mbox file, or his edit
               file in -f.
```

So if you're trying to delete your emails and you use `d *` or `d 1-5`, etc, you need to make sure you leave `mail` using either `quit` or `q`.

I hope this saves someone else my confusion.

Comment: My god, thank you for this. How I wish we could leave these obtuse legacy behaviors behind...